# Entity Framework with SQL Server 2000 (APPLY Operator) issue

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a simple Linq query below:

```
var seq = (from n in GetObjects() 
          select n.SomeKey)
          .Distinct()
          .Count();
```

This query works find with SQL Server 2005 and above.

But, this start to give headache when I hooked the EF to SQL Server 2000. Because EF is using APPLY operator which only SQL Server 2005 and above can be supported. I do not know why the hell EF is using APPLy operator instead of sub queries.

My current work around is:

```
var seq = (from n in GetObjects() 
              select n.SomeKey)
              .Distinct()
              .ToList()
              .Count();
```

But, I can forsee more problems to come. The above query is just a simple one.

Did anyone come across such issue? And how you guys work around it? Or is there a way to force EF not to use APPLY operator?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

How Lun.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you generated your model against a 2005 (or higher) DB. So the GUI designer put a `ProviderManifestToken` value of 2005 or 2008 into the EDMX. This causes the SQL Server provider to generate SQL optimized for those versions. To fix this:

1. Right click your EDMX file.
2. Open with XML editor.
3. Search for `ProviderManifestToken`
4. Change to 2000
5. Save and run.

Comment: Yes, i generated the edmx againts a 2005 development db. But I have changed the value of ProviderManifestToken to 2000, to check if EF is using SQL Server 2000 compatible query. BUT.... unfortunately, EF somehow throw an exception saying the APPLY operator is supported by 2005 and above only, whenever we use complex queries which involve multiple table, agregation etc.

Comment: OK, so the problem is actually completely different than what you said in your question! The EF is not generating the wrong SQL; rather, it is saying that it doesn't know how to express your query in a form which SQL 2000 can handle. These things do happen when you use a 10 year old DB server. The EF cannot magically make SQL 2000 gain all of the SQL verbs required to express anything you can do in LINQ. You need to either change your query or change your DB server.

Comment: I didn't say EF is generating the wrong SQL. As an ORM, EF is "not smart enough" (probably on purpose) to not use APPLY operator when ProviderManifestToken is set to 2000. Changing DB is sometimes a mission impossible to a lot of the medium to large organizations. In my case, no. So, if you notice my question, I am asking if anyone has workaround to make my query above to work with SQL Server 2000 and EF...